# pySerial Program Stops Working Correctly

Tags: python, python-2.7, arduino, serial-port, pyserial

I've been messing around with my Arduino and was creating a program to display tweets on an LCD screen. Unfortunately, the python program I've written to retrieve and send the tweets seems to cease working after a minute or less. It then stops printing any output to the console and only displays a single character on the Arduino every time it updates.

I'm assuming it's a problem with the code related to serial as it runs into the same issue if i remove everything related to twitter. The Arduino code works fine if I send it input from the serial monitor in the Arduino IDE so i think i'm good on that front too.

Below is my code, any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import serial
import tweepy
import time

ser = serial.Serial("COM3", 9600)

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler("authstuff")
auth.set_access_token("accessstuff")

api = tweepy.API(auth)


def find_tweet():
    public_tweets = api.user_timeline("duderitsover")
    tweet = public_tweets[0].user.screen_name + ": " + public_tweets[0].text
    print tweet
    ser.write(tweet.encode('ascii'))



while True:
    print "in loop"
    find_tweet()
    time.sleep(4)
```

And the Arduino code just in case (this is a mess, sorry)

```
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>
#include <String.h>

LiquidCrystal lcd(2, 3, 4, 8, 9, 10, 11);
String long_string = "Long sting long string longer string long string this string is very long";
String data;
String temp_data;

String read_input;
unsigned long current_time;
unsigned long led_delay = 0;
bool has_updated = false;


int dial_position;



void setup() { 
  Serial.begin(9600);
  lcd.begin(16,2);
  pinMode(5, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(5, HIGH);

}

void loop() {
  current_time = millis();

  if (led_delay < current_time) {
    digitalWrite(5, LOW);
    has_updated = false;
  }

  Serial.println(analogRead(A0));
  dial_position = analogRead(A0) / 10;

  if (read_input != "" && read_input != long_string) {
    long_string = read_input;
    has_updated = true;
  }

  if (dial_position < 10) {
    temp_data = long_string.substring(0, 33);
  }
  else if (dial_position < 20) {
    temp_data = long_string.substring(33, 65);
  }
  else if (dial_position < 30) {
    temp_data = long_string.substring(65, 97);
  }
  else if (dial_position < 50) {
    temp_data = long_string.substring(65 + 32, 97 + 32);
  }
  else if (dial_position < 60) {
    temp_data = long_string.substring(65 + 64 + 32, 97 + 64 + 32);
  }
  else if (dial_position < 70) {
    temp_data = long_string.substring(65 + 64 + 64, 97 + 64 + 64);
  }
  else if (dial_position < 80) {
    temp_data = long_string.substring(65 + 128 + 32, 97 + 128 + 32);
  }
  else if (dial_position < 90) {
    temp_data = long_string.substring(65 + 128 + 64, 97 + 128 + 64);
  }
  else if (dial_position < 100) {
    temp_data = long_string.substring(65 + 128 + 96, 97 + 128 + 96);
  }

  if (temp_data != data && temp_data != "") {
    data = temp_data;

    if (temp_data.length() > 16) {
      lcd.clear();
      lcd.print(data.substring(0, 16));
      lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
      lcd.print(data.substring(16, 33));
    }
    else {
      lcd.clear();
      lcd.print(data);
    }

  }
}

void serialEvent(){
  read_input = Serial.readString();
  Serial.println("UPDATING");
  digitalWrite(5, HIGH);
  led_delay = current_time + 2000;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Resolved the issue by using the Serial.reset_input_buffer() command every few times my loop runs, not sure if it's the correct method by it's functional.